# Probability of being first, second, or third in a contest

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Question in the book: 
Suppose that 100 people enter a contest and that different
winners are selected at random for first, second, and third
prizes. What is the probability that Michelle wins one of
these prizes if she is one of the contestants?

**My work**:
Being first: 1/100
Being second: 1/99
Being third: 1/98

So total probablity is 1/100 + 1/99 + 1/98

**Book Answer**:
But the book says 3/100, I understand why kind of, but I don't understand what I did wrong in my work?

Comment: You can draw a parallel to this problem: You think of three numbers between 1 and 100. What is the probability that I can guess one of them right on the first guess? Maybe by looking at the problem like this, you can see what the right and wrong approaches are.

Comment: Why should the probability to become second in this (weird) contest be less than the probability to become first? What if there are e.g. only $3$ contestants? Try to grasp!

Answer (score 1):

The probability of being second/third is *not* $\frac 1{99}, \frac 1{98}$. Then, is the probability of coming $99$th $\frac{1}{100-99} = 1$? Clearly not,right?

Choosing a position for Michelle does not depend upon what position it is. The probability that she comes first, is equal to the probability that she comes second, is equal to the probability that she comes third, because in each case, we have to choose one place out of *hundred* : whether that is the first place, or second place, or third place, or seventy-seventh place, it is still one place out of hundred. Therefore, the probability of each of these events is $\frac 1{100}$, and given that coming first,second and third are mutually exclusive events gives the answer $\frac 3{100}$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your work is that you have to pay attention to the wording of the problem. The question didn't ask you the probability of being first, being second, then being third... it asked you what is the probability of Michelle winning **ONE** of the prizes. Since there are 3 prizes, only 3 people will get a prize. Hence, she has a 3 out of 100 chance of getting a prize.

Answer (score 0):

$1/99$ is the probability of coming second given that she didn't come first.  The chance of not coming first is $99/100$ so the chance of coming second is $$\frac1{99}\frac{99}{100}=\frac1{100}$$